# How do I detect if the computer is playing any sound?

Tags: audio

I want to programmatically detect if a (local) computer (not mobile device) is playing any sound or music. Preferably via some high level api from Java or Python or a similar language.

Comment: Local or remote computer and what platform?

Comment: (And what *particular* language.)

Comment: local, preferably any platform but if nothing general exists then Windows and i already specified preferably Java or Python. i'm not sure what else you could be referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it, but as a first approach I would open (open as input, not output) a fake recording stream on the master windows playback lineout device (instead the normal use of opening the mic or linein device for recording).

I would then monitor the captured frames. If for a certain time there are values over some small threshold, I would infer there is sound.